# route visualisation

Tags: data-visualization, maps

Google maps, for example, is good for finding transport options between two specified locations. It seems less good at displaying all the places that are easily reached from a particular location by a particular option (it doesn't understand "towns within one hour bus journey from here", say).

As a concrete illustration, stagecoach has [a map](https://tiscon-maps-stagecoachbus.s3.amazonaws.com/ZoneMaps/East/CAMBS%20MEGA%20PLUS%20ZONE%20MAP%20-%20APR%202018.pdf) showing the geographical area covered by one of their "megarider plus" bus tickets. Let's say I buy one of these tickets. Perhaps I want to spend the week touring around various towns and I'd like to minimise time travelling and maximise sightseeing.

Say I start in Peterborough. I'd like to see all the relevant bus routes, perhaps limited to direct connections to towns less than an hour away. I might pick some of these to visit and then iterate the process. In the end, I'd have a bunch of possible itineraries.

Do any visualisation tools like this exist?

Obviously, one could manually convert from a list of individual textual route listings but it would nice to have something graphical.

Comment: What OS should the software run on, and how much you'd be willing to invest if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: Web-based or a phone app would be ideal. Typical phone app prices. Bus tickets are tens of pounds so it wouldn't make much sense to pay more or one would just travel by train.

Comment: For what phone OS? Android, iOS, Jolla …?

Comment: Happy to hear about anything that exists aimed at normal consumer and not niche specialist.